# When should we capture the DUMP file for debugging

Tags: c#, crash-dumps

Let's say I have a .NET application that crashes when I close it and I want to use DebugDiag to see what is going on. So we should create a dump file. My question is When do we create this dump file? Should I create it when I start the application? well if I do that it says a dump file has been created at this temp location...ok..then I continue working the application and make it to crash, but my confusion is that well it created the dump file very early, but crash happened at the end, so how even that dump file can be helpful? does it like get updated automatically once we are working with that application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a crash (which is usually an unhandled exception) you should create the dump file when the exception becomes a second chance exception. I am not very familiar with DebugDiag, but tools such as adplus (Debugging Tools for Windows) and ProcDump will both let you create dumps for this.

In some cases you may want to create dumps for first chance exceptions as well (i.e. before any code gets to handle the exception). E.g. if the exception which causes the crash wraps some other exception you may not have enough information at that point. In those cases creating dump files on first chance exceptions will give you detailed information on the state of the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure windows to create dump files when the process crashes. This feature is not enabled by default: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx). The process is different for Windows XP: [Capturing Application Crash Dumps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx). Once you have the dump file you can open it and investigae with [WinDbg](http://geekswithblogs.net/.netonmymind/archive/2006/03/14/72262.aspx). I highly recommend blog by [Tess Fernandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) and this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321578899).

Comment: It says "Applications that do their own custom crash reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by this feature." ... and my application is a .NET app,  so does it mean I cannot use this?

Comment: You can use, it most likely means that .NET app would usually have unhandled exception handler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and there is less use for native dump in .NET world.

Comment: Hmm..that's weird, the article says go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting ..but I have the path upto \Windows...so I don't even have Windows Error Reporting folder in registry...do you think I can just make it myself?

Comment: Try this if you're on XP: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx